# Is there a way to divide a time based event to an hour template in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I Have a data frame with various events with start time and end time.
for example,
[image]

I want an output data frame that is a hour template (hours in columns) and dates in different rows with the same event. And the values to be populated for that corresponding hour and date as '1'.

[image]

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Event':list('abc'),
        'StartTime':['24-12-19 1:14','22-12-19 0:32','23-12-19 6:00'],
        'EndTime':['24-12-19 6:00','24-12-19 4:32','24-12-19 16:00']
})

df[['StartTime','EndTime']] = df[['StartTime','EndTime']].apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)

df1 = (df.melt('Event')
         .set_index('value')
         .groupby('Event')['Event']
         .resample('H')
         .count()
         .reset_index(name='val')
         .assign(val=1, 
                 date=lambda x: x['value'].dt.date, 
                 hour=lambda x: x['value'].dt.hour)
         .set_index(['Event','date','hour'])['val']
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        )
```

---

```
print (df1)

  Event       date  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  ...  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  \
0     a 2019-12-24  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
1     b 2019-12-22  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  ...   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   
2     b 2019-12-23  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  ...   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   
3     b 2019-12-24  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
4     c 2019-12-23  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  ...   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   
5     c 2019-12-24  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  ...   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   

   21  22  23  
0   0   0   0  
1   1   1   1  
2   1   1   1  
3   0   0   0  
4   1   1   1  
5   0   0   0  

[6 rows x 26 columns]
```

**Explanation**:

1. First convert both columns to datetimes by [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)
2. Reshape by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) - so possible [`DataFrameGroupBy.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html) per groups
3. Create new columns with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for set all values of `val` to `1`, dates by [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) and [`Series.dt.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html)
4. Last reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html)
5. Last some data cleaning by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html)

EDIT:

For start and ends of hours use similar solution - for hours subtract floored hours by [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) and if start date also subtract `1`, then use `first` with `resample`:

```
#changed times
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Event':list('abc'),
        'StartTime':['24-12-19 1:20','22-12-19 0:30','23-12-19 6:00'],
        'EndTime':['24-12-19 6:20','24-12-19 4:40','24-12-19 16:00']
})

df[['StartTime','EndTime']] = df[['StartTime','EndTime']].apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)

f = lambda x: x['value'].sub(x['value'].dt.floor('H')).dt.total_seconds().div(3600)
df1 = (df.melt('Event')
         .assign(h = f)
         .assign(h = lambda x: x.h.mask(x.variable == 'StartTime', 1 - x.h))
         .set_index('value')
         .groupby('Event')['h']
         .resample('H')
         .first()
         .fillna(1)
         .reset_index(name='h')
         .assign(date=lambda x: x['value'].dt.date, 
                 hour=lambda x: x['value'].dt.hour)
         .set_index(['Event','date','hour'])['h']
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        )
```

---

```
print (df1)
  Event       date    0         1    2    3         4    5         6    7  \
0     a 2019-12-24  0.0  0.666667  1.0  1.0  1.000000  1.0  0.333333  0.0   
1     b 2019-12-22  0.5  1.000000  1.0  1.0  1.000000  1.0  1.000000  1.0   
2     b 2019-12-23  1.0  1.000000  1.0  1.0  1.000000  1.0  1.000000  1.0   
3     b 2019-12-24  1.0  1.000000  1.0  1.0  0.666667  0.0  0.000000  0.0   
4     c 2019-12-23  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.000000  0.0  1.000000  1.0   
5     c 2019-12-24  1.0  1.000000  1.0  1.0  1.000000  1.0  1.000000  1.0   

  14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23  
0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
1  ...  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  
2  ...  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  
3  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
4  ...  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  
5  ...  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  

[6 rows x 26 columns]
```

EDIT1: Idea is resample by minutes and then aggregate hours:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Event':list('abc'),
        'StartTime':['20-12-19 18:06','22-12-19 0:32','23-12-19 6:00'],
        'EndTime':['20-12-19 18:07','24-12-19 4:32','24-12-19 16:00']
})
```

---

```
df[['StartTime','EndTime']] = df[['StartTime','EndTime']].apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)

f = lambda x: x['value'].sub(x['value'].dt.floor('Min')).dt.total_seconds().div(60)
df1 = (df.melt('Event')
         .assign(h = f)
         .assign(h = lambda x: x.h.mask(x.variable == 'StartTime', 1 - x.h))
         .set_index('value')
         .groupby('Event')['h']
         .resample('Min')
         .first()
         .fillna(1)
         .reset_index(name='h')
         .assign(date=lambda x: x['value'].dt.date, 
                 hour=lambda x: x['value'].dt.hour)
         .groupby(['Event','date','hour'])['h']
         .sum()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .div(60)
          .reset_index()
          .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        )
```

---

```
print (df1)
  Event        date         0    1    2    3         4    5    6    7    8  \
0     a  2019-12-20  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
1     b  2019-12-22  0.466667  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.000000  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0   
2     b  2019-12-23  1.000000  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.000000  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0   
3     b  2019-12-24  1.000000  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.533333  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
4     c  2019-12-23  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0   
5     c  2019-12-24  1.000000  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.000000  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0   

     9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17        18   19   20   21   22  \
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.016667  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.000000  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0   
2  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.000000  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0   
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
4  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.000000  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0   
5  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   

    23  
0  0.0  
1  1.0  
2  1.0  
3  0.0  
4  1.0  
5  0.0
```

Comment: Is there a way to add values as 'hours' instead of 1's?
for example, if the start time is 12:30 , i want to get 0.5 at the 13th hour

Comment: @SuhasMucherla - possible, but more complicated.Also what should be last value per group? e.g. if `24-12-19 10:22` ? It shoud be `22/60` ?

Comment: yes,basically i want the amount of time the event was active at that particular hour, in terms of hours. so it would be 22/60 if it was last value in the group and 38/60 if it was the first value in the group

Comment: The above solution doesn't seem to be working if the StartTime and EndTime of the event is in the same hour, for example, if StartTime is 24-12-19 18:06 andEndTime is 24-12-19 18:07 , i want the 18th hour column to have 1/60. but it doesnt seem to be happening, any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do this:

```
# sample data
d = pd.DataFrame({'Event': ['Event1','Event2'],
                  'StartTime':['2019-01-01 00:10:00', '2019-01-01 13:10:00'],
                  'EndTime':['2019-01-01 11:10:00', '2019-01-01 20:10:00']})

# convert cols to datetime
col = ['StartTime','EndTime']
for c in col:
    d[c] = pd.to_datetime(d[c])

# add a new column containing list of hours
d['hours'] = [[x for x in range(24)] for _ in range(d.shape[0])]

# explode the list into new rows
d = d.explode('hours').reset_index(drop=True)

# calculate the values for each hour
def make_table(f):
    start_hour = int(f['StartTime'].dt.hour.unique())
    hour_diff = (f['EndTime'] - f['StartTime']).astype('timedelta64[h]').tolist()
    max_hour = int(f['EndTime'].dt.hour.unique())
    use_hours = [x for x in range(start_hour, max_hour+1)]
    f['encode'] = f['hours'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x in use_hours else 0)
    return f

# apply the function to each group
d2 = d.groupby(['Event','StartTime','EndTime']).apply(make_table)

# convert d2 into wide format using pivot
d2 = pd.pivot_table(d2, values='encode', index=['Event','StartTime','EndTime'], columns=['hours'])
```

Here's how the output would look like (shown few columns)

```
hours                                           0  1  2  3  4  5  6 ...
Event  StartTime           EndTime                                 
Event1 2019-01-01 00:10:00 2019-01-01 11:10:00  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 ...
Event2 2019-01-01 13:10:00 2019-01-01 20:10:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ...
```